# Lock and thread Pool

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

If a thread in a thread pool is waiting to acquire a lock, then if this thread failed to get that lock then did the .Net schedule this thread to do some other activities.??

Comment: If its scheduled to other activities then how could it be waiting for a lock?

Comment: What do you mean by "failed to get that lock"?

Comment: "Failed to get that lock" means some other thread acquired that lock

Comment: Personally, I think any kind of blocking behaviour in the ThreadPool is an abuse. If you really must, ensure low lock contention and hold on to the lock for the minimal time possible.

Answer (score 6):

No, the thread remains in a waiting state. The thread pool doesn't reuse it for anything else.